# Composition of ROBDD

Tags: algorithm, composition, boolean-logic, binary-decision-diagram

I am trying to understand how the composition of two ROBDDs works.

```
F1 = (d? false: (c? (a? false: true): false))
F2 = (d? (b? true: (a? false: true)): (c? (b? true: (a? false: true)): true))
```

I need to find a formula `F3` that is obtained by replacing all occurrences of `d` by formula `F1` in formula `F2`.

How do I proceed solving this?

Comment: The title says *'Composition of ROBDD'*, but the description seems to imply you want a substitution of one node **(?)** into another ROBDD. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Seems that [section 5.3.2 of this paper](http://www.ecs.umass.edu/ece/labs/vlsicad/ece667/reading/somenzi99bdd.pdf) is covering this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Substitution, composition of BDDs, variable renaming, cofactors, and evaluation are [all the same](https://github.com/tulip-control/dd/issues/12) mathematical operation: substitution. You can do the substitution you are interested in using the [Python package `dd`](https://github.com/tulip-control/dd/blob/master/doc.md) as follows:

```py
import dd.autoref as _bdd


f1_formula = 'ite(d, FALSE, ite(c, ite(a, FALSE, TRUE), FALSE))'
f2_formula = (
    'ite(d, ite(b, TRUE, ite(a, FALSE, TRUE)), '
    'ite(c, ite(b, TRUE, ite(a, FALSE, TRUE)), TRUE))')
# create a BDD manager and BDDs for the above formulas
bdd = _bdd.BDD()
bdd.declare('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
f1 = bdd.add_expr(f1_formula)
f2 = bdd.add_expr(f2_formula)
# substitute `f1` for `d` in `f2`
sub = dict(d=f1)
r = bdd.let(sub, f2)
# dump the BDDs to a PNG file
bdd.dump('foo.png', [f1, f2, r])
print(f'f1: {f1}, f2: {f2}, r: {r}')
```

The above creates the output:

```
f1: @-7, f2: @14, r: @11
```

and the file `foo.png` shown below. For assignments of Boolean values to the variables:

- `f1_formula` corresponds to the negated BDD at node 7
- `f2_formula` corresponds to the BDD at node 14
- `r` (the composition) corresponds to the BDD at node 11.

[image]

The "let" method is named after the `LET... IN` construct in [TLA+](https://lamport.azurewebsites.net/tla/tla.html).